# How do I subscribe to a method in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to do something like this.

```
var foo = function() {
    this.run = function() {
        alert('got');
    }
    this.init = function() {
        this.run();
    }
    this.init();
};

window.onload = function() {
    var f = new foo();
    $(f).bind('run', function() { // this doesn't work
        alert('ran!');
    });
};​
```

It doesn't work though. How can I subscribe to a method of another object?

Comment: when f.run is executed I want alert('ran!'); to execute

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot bind event handlers directly to functions - you bind them to events! You will need to trigger a custom event in run():

```
this.run = function() {
    // Trigger an event called "run"
    $(this).triggerHandler('run');

    // ...
};
```

Now you're able to subscribe to this event the way you already did:

```
var f = new foo();
$(f).on('run', function() { ... }); // "bind" is fine as well
```

This will work for events triggered after the handler has been bound, so the event triggered in the constructor will most likely not be caught.

Comment: I have put it into jsfiddle. It's not working as expected http://jsfiddle.net/uwN4b/1/

Comment: I've added a bit to my answer. Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7PHyA/1/ - you will get "got" two times, but "ran!" only onces. This is because the event handler is bound after triggering the event for the first time.